# How can I bring commits into a branch from another branch based on when they were created after cherry picking and merging?

Tags: git, commit, git-merge, git-rebase

Consider that I have two branches: `master` and `staging`. Commit `C` was made on `staging` and cherry-picked into `master` urgently, so it's already there.

```
-x-x-x-A-B-C-D (staging)
      /     
-x-x-x-C (master)
```

Later, another branch `feature` was merged directly into `master`, so two commits were added to `master`, the commit `E` and the merge commit `F`.

```
-x-x-x-A-B-C-D (staging)
      /     
-x-x-x-C-E-F (master)
```

I need to get what is in `master` into `staging` to get a clean merge of `staging` into `master`. I end up with duplicate commits because of the cherry-pick if I just use merges. If I rebase instead: `git checkout staging && git rebase origin/master` I get `A`, `B`, and `D` on top (although, I don't think the merge commit `F` comes in unless I use `--rebase-merges`, could be wrong though):

```
-x-x-x-C-E-F-A-B-D (staging)
```

But what if I wanted those three commits to be merged in based on when they were actually created and end up with:

```
-x-x-x-A-B-C-D-E-F (staging)
```

Is this possible and does it make sense at all to do this? Or am I better off putting `A`, `B`, and `D` on top?

Here are what I believe are the relevant parts of the result for `git log --graph master`. I added the commit letters I used in the question after each commit hash.

```
*   commit c0ead31e3f7a7f6e077b2bbb947775dcd2dc3453 (**F**) (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
|\  Merge: b943c0fd 07a7dd24
| | Author: Author
| | Date:   Tue Nov 22 03:23:09 2022 +0000
| |
| |     Merge branch 'feature' into 'master'
| |
| |     <commit message for feature>
| |
| |     See merge request company/project!24
| |
| * commit 07a7dd245bec741e1c077d055558b3930c570a3f (**E**)
|/  Author: Author
|   Date:   Tue Nov 22 03:20:57 2022 +0000
|
|       <commit message for feature>
|
* commit b943c0fd70e5ba64b70b03721ab2962facaecbc3 (**C**)
| Author: Author
| Date:   Wed Oct 19 18:49:58 2022 +0000
|
|     <commit message>
|
|
|     (cherry picked from commit e1598f670d0e78e76ee0e54a4a4668e7186adbab)
|
```

Comment: Just to get clear: If `feature` was merged into `master` that would cause _one_ commit to be added to `master`, the merge commit F. So where did E come from?

Comment: At least in the GitLab UI, when I merged `feature` into `master`, I got two commits in `master`. The commit that I made on `feature` which was the code for the feature, as well as the merge commit.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me; a move that creates _two_ commits on `master` would not be a merge. Maybe you did a "rebase merge", in which case neither E nor F is a merge commit. Can you show the actual diagram of what the history of `staging` looks like?

Comment: Another thing to understand is that the same commit cannot be in two places. C is not on both master and staging. The thing you got when you cherry-picked C is a _copy_ of C, which we might call `C'` (pronounced C-prime).

Comment: The merge of `feature` into `master` was done through the GitLab UI via a merge request if that helps. I made a commit `E` on `feature`, then did a merge request of `feature` into `master` without commit squashing, and it shows commit `E` as well as a merge commit `F` in the commit history on `master`.

Comment: Got it, I was wondering what the apostrophe was for in other diagrams.

Comment: As I said, that makes no sense to me. Do you know how to get a graph of the topology and show it to us?

Comment: I do not but I can get it over to you if you could let me know how to!

Comment: Is `staging` a shared branch, or is it effectively another `feature` branch that you alone are using?

Comment: Regarding the questions around merge commit `F`, the issue is that your graph does not show a merge commit. (A merge commit must have at least two parents and thus at least two lines coming out of it.) The command `git log --graph master` should show you the proper graph and will identify what the other parent commit is. It might even be commit `C` if `feature` was already up to date with `master` at the time of the merge. I don't think this changes your question though, but it could clear up this aspect of the discussion.

Comment: Thank you @TTT, I've updated the question with the graph result

Comment: What's the problem with "duplicated" commits? As long as your _tree_ looks good, why care?

Answer (score 0):

The phrase `git checkout staging && git rebase origin/master` rebases `staging` onto `master`, which seems to be just the opposite of you want. What you want is more like rebase E and F from `master` onto `staging`. Keep in mind that rebase is just cherry-pick, so you could achieve this by cherry-picking E and then F.

If, as you claim, F is a merge commit, then you would have to specify its parent, like this:

```
git switch staging
git cherry-pick <SHA of E>
git cherry-pick -m1 <SHA of F>
```

But I am more inclined to think that there was no merge, even though you claim there was, so that all you have to do is say

```
git switch staging
git cherry-pick <SHA of E>
git cherry-pick <SHA of F>
```

Comment: Note that you may well get merge conflicts in the course of this. But that's just life; you simply will have to resolve them.

Comment: This does work to get E and F commits on top of my staging branch, but, the only problem I find is that when I do a merge request for staging into master after cherry-picking, I get duplicated E and F commits in master. The ones that are already there in master, and then the ones that I cherry-picked into staging.

Comment: Did you also want to delete E and F from master? `git switch master && reset --hard <SHA of C>`

Comment: I need E and F in master for sure but I suppose I could just remove them from master right before the merge.